# Change the default value of "Modified By" field for SharePoint online files modified by Graph API based app

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have multiple processes modifying files in a SharePoint site via the Graph API. When any of the processes modify the SharePoint files via the Graph API the value of the "Modified By" field changes to "SharePoint App". To be able to differentiate the actions taken by the scripts, I would like to have the name of the modifying process displayed as the field value. The Graph API documentation [mentions the field is read only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0). How can I have the script/application name displayed in the "Modified By" field?

Comment: "Modified By" field is read-only. Is it acceptable for you to create a custom field where would you store the script/application name?

Answer (score 0):

Per my research, there is no such graph api to update read-only field currently. As a workaround, I would recommend you to use rest api to update this column or you can set the "Modified By" field read-only properties to false by following powershell script

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
 
Function Set-SPOFieldReadOnly($SiteURL, $ListName, $FieldInternalName, [Bool]$IsReadOnly)
{
    Try {
        #Get Credentials to connect
        $Cred= Get-Credential
  
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
  
        #Get the List
        $List=$Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
 
        #Get the Field
        $Field = $List.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle($FieldInternalName)
        $Field.ReadOnlyField = $IsReadOnly
        $Field.Update()
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  
        Write-host -f Green "Read Only Settings Update for the Field Successfully!"
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
#Set parameter values
$SiteURL = "https://Crescent.sharepoint.com"
$ListName = "Team Documents"
$FieldInternalName = "Editor" #Internal Name
$IsReadOnly = $False
 
Set-SPOFieldReadOnly -SiteURL $SiteURL -ListName $ListName -FieldInternalName $FieldInternalName -IsReadOnly $IsReadOnly
```